# Создание адресной книги. Проблема с добавлением нового контакта

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог вбить имя и номер контакта, и чтобы он сохранился в словаре.
Я, если честно, не представляю как это можно осуществить
Мне нужно, чтобы контакты сохранялись после перезапуска программы

```
ab = {  "Мама" : "890878xxx07",
        "Папа" : "890878xxt07"
}


print("Выберите действие:")
print("1)Добавить контакт")
print("2)Удалить контакт")
print("3)Просмотреть список всех контактов")
print("4)Изменить контакт")
print("5)Найти контакт")

act = input("Действие: ")

if act == "1":
    nam = input("Введите имя: ")
    num = input("Введите номер: ")
    ab[nam] = num
```

Comment: Ваш код хорошо работает. С чем у вас проблемы?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, чтобы контакты сохранялись после перезапуска программы?

Comment: Да, мне нужно, чтобы контакты сохранялись после перезапуска программы

Comment: @SiRex2307 ну так добавьте работу с файлами. В начале кода добавьте считывание из файла. При выходе - сохранение в файл. Для этого можно сделать ещё один пункт меню - "Выход"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтение словаря:

```
ab = {}
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    s = line.split("|")
    ab[s[0]] = s[1]
f.close()
```

Запись словаря:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
for key, val in ab.items():
    s = key + "|" + val + '\n'
    f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Comment: too many values to unpack (expected 2) - выдает такую ошибку, код для записи вставил в самом низу. Строка for key, val in ab:

Comment: for key, val in ab.items(): - если ab это словарь

Comment: @ivan_susanin а, точно, спасибо. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @SiRex2307 проверьте, исправил

Comment: Благодарю, все работает